# What's the recommended way to style label and values in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm familiar with styling forms with label for="my_id" and input type tags.  I really like how it automatically styles the form components if the form width goes down to a narrower width, and I like that the input tags are left align.

I would like to do the same type of styling except now I'm wanting to display a record where the labels and their values are being styled similarly.

Here's some code that I hoped would work but it doesn't.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="full_name"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
    <span id="full_name">John Smith</span>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="phone"><strong>Long Phone Label:</strong></label>
    <span id="phone">(800) 555-1212/span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on the right way to do this without resorting to tables?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. What "automatically  styles the form components"? Which "same type of styling" are you referring to? "Styled similarly" to what? Also I doubt you should/can use a label like this. Label `for` attributes are supposed to reference form controls not spans. Why can't you use a table? This looks like a prime example for the proper usage of a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems that you want to align the text in the way the form is aligned.The below code will align the labels with their values.This is what i understand from your question.i hope the below code will help you.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Common/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Common/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.js"></script>

<style>
#b {
    left: 156px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="header">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="a">
    <label for="full_name"><strong>Name:</strong></label><br>
    <label for="phone"><strong>Long Phone Label:</strong></label>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="b">
    <span id="full_name">John Smith</span><br>
    <span id="phone">(800) 555-1212</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The solution you provided isn't working the way I'd like.  It is displaying the name and phone labels above the content.  I was hoping for Name: John Smith and then on the next line Long Phone Label: (800) 555-1212.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work. You could use a JQM grid to do a side by side label:

Label: Input Element
Label: Input Element

Be careful though as labels for mobile are like that on purpose. It's so you can see the lable and the input when entering on a device like an Ihone:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><strong>I'm Block A</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><strong>I'm Block B</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
</div>
```